# CSS subsclass without parent class

Tags: css

I have two items

One with classes:

```
navbar__item dropdown-wrap navbar__item-layout
```

and two with classes:

```
navbar__item dropdown-wrap
```

I want like to hide item two without hide item one.

Comment: Post some relevant HTML as well.

Comment: Does `navbar__item dropdown-wrap navbar__item-layout {visibility: visible;} navbar__item dropdown-wrap {visibility: hidden;}`not work?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/)

Comment: you mean showing inner class with in hidden parent? I don't think it's possible.

Comment: Take a look. I have posted an answer which might help your case. Remember, CSS hierachies are followed regardless of any ruling directive; so, if I understand it correctly, you don't want the second to get affected by the first, use the `:not` directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple using the `:not(X)` directive where `X` is the selector you don't want the styling rules to apply.

Let's take the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h2 class="navbar__item dropdown-wrap navbar__item-layout">Hello</h2>
  <h2 class="navbar__item dropdown-wrap">Hello 2</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
.navbar__item.dropdown-wrap:not(.navbar__item-layout) {
  font-size: 11em;
}
```

This should work in your case! :)

---

**What are we doing here?**

We are telling the CSS style processor that we want to apply the style rules to items with the classes `.navbar__item .dropdown-wrap` but at the same time, the element can't contain the class `.navbar__item-layout`. You can go pretty complex by using `:nth-child` or `parent`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using :nth-child (see more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)).

Comment: `nth-child` is pretty static when it comes to listed items.